# Power supply to Nano Connect RP2040

Tags: power

I have had a draft design for interconnected boards where the designer has a 12vdc ac/dc converter on a power board, which is cabled to a base board that bucks down the 12v to 5v via a regulator, which feeds 5v components & a 3.3v buck regulator - supplying 3.3v components. The drawing below shows the base board (fed by the power board), with that base board also connected to a MCU board via ribbon cable. The MCU is an Arduino Nano Connect RP2040.

Owing to space constraints, the power board must be seperate and will be 6" to 24" away from the other board. The MCU board is next to the base board.

All components on the connected boards take (or should take) 5vdc or less. One exception that I can see is a mosfet which has a 12vdc base.

If that mosfet is changed to a 5vdc or less base, could the 12v to 5v converter and related circuitry be eliminated and instead use a 5vdc ac/dc converter to supply subseqeunt circuits?

[image: Base board]

Comment: Sorryn this is off topic here. May be better suited for electrical stackexchange. And is your question "Can I remove the 12V supply if I don't need 12V"? Because of course you can remove it when you don't need 12V

Comment: The -12V gate of the MOSFET is the *absolute maximum*. The threshold is typically only -1V. Changing to a different input voltage will just mean changing your voltage divider for the input power detection.